# OutlookViewCtrl Access Shared Calendar

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, outlook-calendar

```
AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.OutlookViewCtrl.AxViewCtrl AxViewCtl1;
```

I am using the OutlookViewCtrl so that I can access mail inside my application, the mail is contained within public folders so it is relatively easy to access by setting the  AxViewCtl1.Folder path accordingly.

I would now like to access shared calendars in the same way. The calendars are not stored in the public folders, so are added to outlook under the Shared Calendars section.

Is there a way to access these?

Currently I am only able to access my Calender when setting AxViewCtl1.Folder  to "Calendar".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just reading past looking for an answer on something else regarding the outlook view control but I just read a post earlier saying you can specify the folder like

```
AxViewCtl1.Folder = @"\\Personal Folders\Folder";
```

would it be worth trying to use this to specify the root folder by a couple of backslashes?

```
AxCiewCtl1.Folder = @"\\Shared Root\Folder you want";
```

Anyway here is the page.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479345.aspx